# Why I am receiving null in my output?

Tags: sockets, java-me, tcp

I want to send a message to my computer from my phone using TCP..My computer is the server and my phone is the client. I am able to send a message from my phone to my computer but in the output, I get null characters ..

I paste my codes below;;

Client ::

public void startApp() {
         try {
      // establish a socket connection with remote server
      streamConnection =
      (StreamConnection) Connector.open(connectString);

```
  // create DataOuputStream on top of the socket connection
  outputStream = streamConnection.openOutputStream();
  dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

  // send the HTTP request
  dataOutputStream.writeChars("Hello");
  dataOutputStream.flush();

  // create DataInputStream on top of the socket connection
  inputStream = streamConnection.openInputStream();
  dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

  // retrieve the contents of the requested page from Web server
  String test="";
  int inputChar;
  System.out.println("Entering read...........");
  while ( (inputChar = dataInputStream.read()) != -1) {
     // test=test+((char)inputShar);
    results.append((char) inputChar);
  }
  System.out.println("Leaving read...........");
  // display the page contents on the phone screen
  //System.out.println(" Result are "+results.toString());
  System.out.println("   ");
  resultField = new StringItem(null, results.toString());
  System.out.println("Client says "+resultField);
  resultScreen.append(resultField);
  myDisplay.setCurrent(resultScreen);

} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Exception caught:" + e);
} finally {
  // free up I/O streams and close the socket connection
  try {
    if (dataInputStream != null)
      dataInputStream.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {}
  try {
    if (dataOutputStream != null)
      dataOutputStream.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {}
  try {
    if (outputStream != null)
      outputStream.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {}
  try {
    if (inputStream != null)
      inputStream.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {}
  try {
    if (streamConnection != null)
      streamConnection.close();
  } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}

}
```

My server :

public class Main {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // TODO code application logic here
  try{
      ServerSocket sck=new ServerSocket(880);
      Socket client=sck.accept();
      InputStream inp= client.getInputStream();
      int  i;
      OutputStream out=client.getOutputStream();
      out.write("Testing ".getBytes());
      System.out.println("Server has responded          ");
      String str="";
      while((i=inp.read())!=-1){

          str=str+((char) i);
           System.out.println("USer says "+ str);
      }

  }
  catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error "+e);
  }

}
```

}

My output for the server ;;

Server has responded
USer says null H
User says null H null
User says null H null e
etc etc

I am not supposed to get this null character,why I am getting it??
Another thing, my server is writing to the stream but the client is not able to receive that,why is that?Do I need to use a separate thread for that?

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that isn't your real code, and that your real code initialized str to null.

Comment: You must have done. The code you posted doesn't behave as you describe. The only way str can contain the text null is if you put it there, or if was initially null.